# Why does this line of code work in this way?

Tags: python

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    print "DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b


print "Let's do some math with just functions!"

age = add(30, 5)
height = subtract(78, 4)
weight = multiply(90, 2)
iq = divide(100, 2)

print "Age: %d, Height: %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)



print "Here is a puzzle."

# why does the line of code below work in this way?
what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))

print "That becomes: ", what, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

The first thing that the line below the comment does is to call the function divide. I'm curious, why does it do that? Is it because python actually understands the order of operations or is it because of the chain structure that this line has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it. How would you call `add()` when you don't know what the result of `subtract()` is? How would you call `subtract()` if you don't know what the result of `multiply()` is? Finally, how would you call `multiply()` if you don't know what the result of `divide()` is?

As with algebraic notation, operations inside parentheses get done first. If there are parentheses inside parentheses, the innermost operations are done first. It can't work any other way.

Answer (score 3):

Before calling a function, Python has to evaluate the parameters passed to that function.  (There's no other choice -- the values of the parameters can only be passed in if they are known.)

Applying this principle recursively, the only choice is to first call `divide()` -- before this, the arguments to no other function are known.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple - all function **arguments have to be evaluated before a call** to function.

In this case:

```
what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))
```

To calculate the value of `add(...)` you have to calculate value of `age` and

```
subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2)))
```

To calculate the value of `subtract(...)` you have to calculate value of `height` and

```
multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Python (and any language with functions) understands the order of operations of function calls.

If you have some functions f(), g(), and h(), a statement like

```
f(g(h()))
```

Needs the result of h() in order to call g(), and the result of g(h()) is needed before it can call f().